# SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word on typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have not a project, just starting to learn typescript, so I have just one file main.ts with this code:

```
enum MiColor {Red=0, Green=1, Blue=2};
console.log(MiColor);
let backgroundColor = MiColor.Green;
```

there is not exists a compilation error, but when I try to run the code in my terminal

```
node main.ts
```

I got this error.
so, why I have a runtime error as node not recognize typescript?

```
enum MiColor {Red=0, Green=1, Blue=2};
^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47←[39m
```

node.js version:    12.16.3

typescript Version: 4.0.2

Comment: You have to compile it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though your file is .ts you are running as if it was JavaScript.

Install ts-node and run from it `npm i -g ts-node`, then you run your project with `ts-node main.ts`